# How to represent 2 dates on a gantt chart?

Tags: info-visualisation, information-architecture, charts

On a gantt chart that I'm doing, there are 2 dates to show: target start/end date and actual start/end date.

I'm not sure what's the best way to represent these 2 dates without it seeming like the other one is the progress indicator (see task 1 example).

[image]

Comment: What is the difference between target and actual? One is meant as reference, in that screen, and the other is editable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought of this solution:

[image]

Basically I used the concept of the [Burndown Chart](https://confluence.atlassian.com/agile/files/391087321/762876973/1/1436759811865/gh_burndown-chart.png) where a line is used as "orientation" of the expected result and then the bar himself is the current progress. The use of 2 distinct shapes (line and rectangle) can help solving the issue "without it seeming like the other one is the progress indicator" as you mentioned.

Hope it helps.